# Can I get a function list in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm a longtime Codewright user on the PC for doing software and I recently moved over to iPhone development and have been learning to use Xcode.  Is there a way to see a function list for the current open file so I can quickly move around in my source files like I could back in Codewright?  Or do I have to just create book marks?

Keith

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At about the center of the top bar in the editor window is a drop-down listing all methods, functions and several other things. Some note-worthy things you can get into this list:

A section header "Some Text":

```
#pragma mark Some Text
```

A line:

```
#pragma mark -
```

A bold "FIXME: Something to do"

```
// FIXME: Something to do
```

FIXME: and TODO: are magic strings here. It's not just any random string.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer so quickly.  This will be a big help

Comment: for anyone using a similar search as I just did to discover this answer far in the future: you can write `#pragma mark - some text` to add a divider followed by a section header without needing two pragma lines.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the document listings using "Command+2", and then expand the "Functions" entry to have the list of all functions in the document.